# Regex target specific word based on two start-of-line conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a series of lines in a text area (specifically a codeMirror window). I want to change the colour of (select) all instances of a word (e.g. string1) IF the line starts with a specific different word (e.g. string2). There could be any number of words between string2 and string 1 if it exists.

I'm quite new to regex, all the examples I can find for this target all of the line from string2 to string1 rather than only targeting string1.

Thanks for the help!

Edit:

I had already worked out I can target the entire line using `^string2(.*string1.*)$` but to clarify, I'm looking to target only the word "string1" if the line that string1 is on starts with "string2"

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question, also if you don't know regex how you know regex is the solution to your problem? Anyway, if I understood you, I think you want to do: `^string2.*string1`

Comment: You cannot do this without lookbehind.

Comment: " if you don't know regex how you know regex is the solution to your problem?" I said that I'm NEW to regex not that I know nothing about it. The Javascript library I'm using requires regex for it's syntax highlighter so I have to use it.

Answer (score 0):

to target all lines starting with *string2* and containing *string1*:

```
^(string2.*?)string1(.*)$
```

now, `$1` has the first part of the line *before* `string1`, and `$2` has the part of the line *after* `string1`.

...which would let use a replacement string of your choosing, for example to turn all `string1` red (not sure if this is html or not but you get the idea):

```
$1<span class='red'>string1</span>$2
```

Comment: This will highlight the entire line, which is not what he wants. He wants to highlight only `string1`.

Comment: unfortunately the pattern itself must match more than *just* string1, given no lookbehinds. this is what capture groups are for.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the reply, but I only want to target the text "string1", not the entire line.